# Programa no funciona como deberia leyendo el fichero

Tags: c

El programa no parece ejecutar los fscanf para leer los datos de un fichero. Yo necesito recoger una serie de datos de este fichero (cada uno almacenados en una variable) ,pero al ejecutarlo (compila sin ningun *warning* ni error) no me hace nada de lo pedido.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(){
  char A[100],B[100],nombre[100],apellido1[100],apellido2[100],salto[100];
  int i=0,e=0;
  float notas[100];
  FILE *fichero1;
  FILE *fichero2;
  do{
    printf("Escribe el fichero que quieres abrir:");
    scanf("%s",A);
    fichero1=fopen(A,"r");
    if (fichero1==NULL){
      perror("No puedo abrir el fichero");
    }else{
      printf("He podido abrir el fichero.\n");
    }
  }
  while(fichero1==NULL);

  do{
    fscanf(fichero1,"%s %s %s",nombre[i],apellido1[i],apellido2[i]);
    printf("%s %s %s",nombre[i],apellido1[i],apellido2[i]);
    do{
      fscanf(fichero1,"%f",notas[e]);
      printf("%f",notas[e]);
      e=e+1;
    }
    while(e<5);
    i=i+1;
  }
  while(!feof(fichero1));

  printf("Escribe el fichero en el que quieres escribir:");
  scanf("%s",B);
  fichero2=fopen(B,"w");

  fclose(fichero1);
  fclose(fichero2);
}
```

Fernando Pérez Pérez 3.4 4.5 8.5 9.0 6.3

Comment: nombre[i] es un carácter no una cadena, pon solo nombre

Comment: Para guardar las notas debes pasar un puntero a float, pon &notas[e]

Answer (score 0):

Para procesar por lo menos una linea deberias cambiar el codigo a:

```
fscanf(fichero1,"%s %s %s",nombre,apellido1,apellido2);
printf("%s\n %s\n %s\n",nombre,apellido1,apellido2);
do{
    fscanf(fichero1,"%f",&notas[e]);
    printf("%f",notas[e]);
    e=e+1;
}
while(e<5);
```